# Parse input columns in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm a Gnuplot newbie, and I'm trying to build a graph from an input .dat file.
The first column in my .dat file is a number which is similar to a "build number", and I'm trying to use those numbers as the values of one of the columns.

For this .dat file:

```
#Version-Number     Average-Error       Average-Performance 
1                       4.100333            41.76998            
2                       4.100333            41.76998
```

I get the correct columns 1 and 2.

But for this .dat file:

```
#Version-Number     Average-Error       Average-Performance 
0.80.0.17598        4.100333            41.76998            
0.80.0.17599        4.100333            41.76998
```

I get columns like: 0.792 0.794 0.796...
And the value I'm looking for (4.100333) falls on 0.8.

This is the .dat file I have: (called CompareResults.dat)

```
#Version-Number    Average-Error       Average-Performance 
0.80.0.17598        4.100333            41.76998            
0.80.0.17599        4.100333            41.76998            
0.80.0.17602        4.100333            41.76998            
0.80.0.17622        4.100333            41.76998
```

and I'm attaching my code.

```
set terminal wxt size 1000,800
set multiplot layout 2, 1 title "Compare Graphs" font ",18"
set tmargin 2
set boxwidth 1 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set grid nopolar
set grid noxtics nomxtics ytics nomytics noztics nomztics \
 nox2tics nomx2tics noy2tics nomy2tics nocbtics nomcbtics
set grid layerdefault   linetype 0 linewidth 1.000,  linetype 0 linewidth 1.000
set pointsize 2
set xtics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set xtics   ()
set ytics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set ztics border in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set cbtics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set rtics axis in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set title "Average Error Graph" font ",12"
set xlabel "Build Number" 
set ylabel "Average Error" 
set lmargin 8
set rmargin 4
set tmargin 4
set bmargin 4
plot 'CompareResults.dat' using 1:2 notitle with lines lc rgb "red" lw 3, '' using         1:2:2 with labels offset 1,0.5 notitle

set title "Performance Graph" font ",12"
set xlabel "Build Number" 
set ylabel "Performance" 
plot 'CompareResults.dat' using 1:3:xtic(1) notitle with lines lc rgb "green" lw 3, '' using 1:3:3 with labels offset 1,0.5 notitle
unset multiplot
reset
```

Thanks a lot!!!
Idan.

Comment: Can I suggest that you (1) remove the noise like tics formatting, limiting the code to just the real action, and (2) attach a picture that gives some idea of what you want to see in the end? I tried a while with your data and code but fail to see so far what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Hi,I tried to add images, but I don't have enough reputation, so it didn't let me... Anyway, seems like our guys here changed they're demands so it is no longer required. Thanks anyway!!!